# Заменить значение у ключа, если оно None

Tags: python, map, dict

Есть словарь `d`, некоторые значения которого могут быть `None`. Как заменить определённое значение ключа `k` на `v`, если оно равно `None`?

```
d = {'k1': None, 'k2': 42}
k = 'k1'
v = 42

if d[k] is None:
    d[k] = v
```

Проблема в том, что тут 2 доступа по ключу. Можно ли сделать это за 1 доступ?

Comment: @Alpensin можно в виде кода? `if old_v := d[k] is None: old_v = v` не меняет значение

Comment: Да, по поводу переменной неправ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

вариант 1:

```
d[k] = v if d[k] is None else d[k]
```

вариант 2:

```
d = dict((key, v if key == k and value is None else value) for key, value in d.items())
```

вариант 2 хорош тем, что если ключ `k` отсутствует в словаре, то не будет ошибки, а для первого случая пришлось бы делать код:

```
if k in d:
    d[k] = v if d[k] is None else d[k]
```

или вообще:

```
if k in d and d[k] is None:
    d[k] = v
```

Comment: Первый вариант аналогичен, а второй ещё дольше

Comment: @mount, что значит не меняет значение? и первый вариант и второй вроде как работают

Comment: Я не говорил, что не меняют значение ваши варианты. Я говорю, что по количеству доступов они такие же или хуже

Comment: @mount, кол-во доступов надо смотреть уже в исполнимом коде, а не в скрипте, потому что в итоговом вариант что 1, что 2, что еще какой-то вариант могут быть свёрнуты в один код. Вы же понимаете, что код `arr[i] |= value`, к примеру, тоже имеет 2 доступа к элементу, хотя выглядит как один